# Domain redirect with 2 domains

Tags: url, redirect, dns

I have 2 domain names that I would like to direct to the same website.

Is it possible to show in the address the domain name they used to get to the site?

e.g.

if a user followed a link for A.com/URL the address bar shows A.com/URL

if a user followed a link for B.com/URL the address bar shows B.com/URL

Thanks in advance

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

---

Just resolve two domain to the same IP address.